# Tesseract how to create the all files

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

I'm testing LicensePlateDetector from Emgu.CV and it works perfectly with an english license plates.

Then I download from tesserac-ocr PT files(because i want to work with portuguese license plates), but when i unziped the file i only have one simple file: "por.traineddata". And if I pass this file to my namespace /tessdata, the LicensePlateDetector does not work.

where i download the file:
[image]
[image]

How do i create the "DangAmbigs", "freq-dawg", "inttemp", "normproto", "pffmtable", "unicharset", "user-words" and "word-dawg" files?

thanks

[image]

the instance

```
/// <summary>
  /// Create a license plate detector
  /// </summary>
  public LicensePlateDetector()
  {
     //create OCR engine
     _ocr = new Tesseract();

     //You can download more language definition data from
     //http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list
     //Languages supported includes:
     //Dutch, Spanish, German, Italian, French and English
     _ocr.Init(null, "eng", false);
  }
```

Comment: This sounds like he downloaded the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

Those English data files are Tesseract 2.0x version. So try download Portuguese data for the same version.

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-2.01.por.tar.gz&can=2&q=